# How to use same interfaces settings for all wlan devices

Tags: debian, usb, network-interface, bridge

I am working with a pcengines apu2c4 board with debian 8.4 installed.Obviously when you insert a wifi dongle new to the machine it is given wlan0, wlan1, wlan2 etc... Is there a way of making all future wifi devices use the same settings in /etc/network/interfaces instead of making a new section in interfaces every time a new adapter is plugged in?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to have an entry in `/etc/udev/rules/70-persistent-net.rules` that allocates the same `wlan0` name to any wlan device that it detects.

e.g. On one of my systems, I have a TP-Link TL-WN721N that has the following rule:

```
# USB device 0x:0x (ath9k_htc) TP-Link TL-WN721N
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

If I wanted to turn that into a generic rule that matched any WLAN device, regardless of the MAC address etc, I'd comment out or delete that rule and replace it with something like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

Note: This **WILL** cause you problems if you later find you need two wlan devices installed or otherwise need to distinguish between different wlan devices.

I just re-read your question.  It seems like you might already have two wlan devices in the machine.  I'm not sure if what you want is possible in that situation unless one of the devices is always the same (and has its own udev rule that comes before the generic rule) while the second device varies.

One possible method is to run something like `sed -i -e '/wlan/d' /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` on every reboot or from a root shell (and remember to make `udev` reload its config) before you swap the wlan usb adaptors.  I know this works with eternet devices because I have to do something very similar whenever I replace a machine's motherboard or PCI-e ethernet card, or clone a system to new hardware.

Also Note: this works with a `sysvinit` debian system.  I have no idea if it works the same on a `systemd` machine - the only `systemd` machine I have doesn't have a wlan interface, only ethernet. and I really don't feel like messing with it's network config right now, it was hard enough getting `systemd` to do what I wanted when I replaced its NIC (by replacing its motherboard) a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share the same IP config/network between several interfaces configure bridging.

In Debian it should be something similar to this:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan1
    iface wlan1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports wlan0 wlan1
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You also need to load the bonding kernel module.

Add to /etc/modules

```
bonding
```

Please read: [Network Card Bonding and Bridging On CentOS and Debian](http://kaivanov.blogspot.pt/2010/09/network-card-bonding-on-centos.html)